# Excel and =sumproduct

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I was making a sheet with excel and then I needed to apply sumproduct to sum the price multiplied by it quantity. Then, I needed to find the sum of them BUT the red lines. So what I've made: I put the full sumproduct (B:B;C:C) and then, subtracted every other sumproduct from the red lines.

My question is: is there any other way to make this function works? Like, simplify this function? If so, how?

There's an image of my sheet here:

[image]

Comment: You could make a custom UDF in VBA to handle removing any "red" lines.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B:B,C:C)-B5*C5-B14*C14-B16*C16
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply **change your quantities on the red lines to negative** and use the simple formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B:B, C:C)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could start by calculating every price in D

- put this code in D2:

  ```
  =$B2*$C2
  ```
- Then select D2 and drag it down so the formula is copied down in the column.

I don't know the rule for something to be red.
I pretended it was red if the price was higher then 15 for each piece.

So I filled in at F2:

```
=SUMIF(C2:C16;"<15,00";D2:D16)
```

The "<15,00" means everything under 15 won't be counted, you can replace this with your own statement.

And at F3:

```
=SUM(D2:D16)
```

This is my result (withouth the red columns)

http://prntscr.com/6060gb

Maybe it helped you out, it's not easier, but i'm sure it works (I tested it)